# Multiple nested views in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to nest views in an ionic template. I have an abstract template working correctly, but the issue is that this particular view is cobbled together from multiple components that I would like to be able to reuse.

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div>
            <ion-nav-view name="home-search"></ion-nav-view>
            <ion-nav-view name="home-dashboard"></ion-nav-view>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And have two separate templates, one for searching and one for the dashboard.

I have finally understood how abstract templates are supposed to be used, so if I comment out one of those, say the dashboard, then use a route like /home/search, it will fill out the view correctly, but be missing the dashboard (obviously).

My hacky way to fix this would be to embed the search bar in the dashboard and the dashboard in the home page, then I would be able to reuse the search bar whereever I want, but the dashboard would be coupled to the search bar.

So my question basically is: what is the appropriate way to go about using multiple partial views (or nested templates) to put together a view for an ionic app.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: See this if it helps http://codepen.io/ItsLeeOwen/pen/faCql

Comment: I am able to embed a single template into another just fine. I really need to be able to embed two separate templates inside the main one. Also this should not require any clicking to make it appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make one of them as a directive you can see this link to figure out how to use directive   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: This may be the only way to do it. It's hard to believe that ionic has no support for multiple partial views, and it is pretty inconvenient for several things we need to do, but I guess it's our best option....

Comment: Parameterizing directives does indeed seem to be the best answer to this issue.